# How to linking OR-Tools to my CMake project?

Tags: c++, cmake, or-tools

Below is a small working example of how to link OR-Tools to a CMake project.

Thanks to [mizux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5710233/mizux) and [kamilcuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9072753/kamilcuk) for your help.

Also, [mizux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5710233/mizux) it might be good to update the documentation to specify that "USE_SCIP=OFF" might be required to solve error arising when building using FetchContent.

**Solution:**

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(my_proj VERSION 1.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

# Build OR-tools dependencies.
set(BUILD_DEPS ON)

# Disable SCIP solver.
set(USE_SCIP OFF)

# Fetch OR-tools library and create the alias ortools::ortools.
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
        or-tools
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/or-tools.git
        GIT_TAG        master
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(or-tools)

# Create a main calling operations_research::BasicExample() and link the or-tools library.
add_executable(myapp main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myapp ortools::ortools)
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "ortools/linear_solver/linear_solver.h"

namespace operations_research {

    void BasicExample() {
        // Create the linear solver with the GLOP backend.
        std::unique_ptr<MPSolver> solver(MPSolver::CreateSolver("GLOP"));

        // Create the variables x and y.
        MPVariable* const x = solver->MakeNumVar(0.0, 1, "x");
        MPVariable* const y = solver->MakeNumVar(0.0, 2, "y");

        LOG(INFO) << "Number of variables = " << solver->NumVariables();

        // Create a linear constraint, 0 <= x + y <= 2.
        MPConstraint* const ct = solver->MakeRowConstraint(0.0, 2.0, "ct");
        ct->SetCoefficient(x, 1);
        ct->SetCoefficient(y, 1);

        LOG(INFO) << "Number of constraints = " << solver->NumConstraints();

        // Create the objective function, 3 * x + y.
        MPObjective* const objective = solver->MutableObjective();
        objective->SetCoefficient(x, 3);
        objective->SetCoefficient(y, 1);
        objective->SetMaximization();

        solver->Solve();

        LOG(INFO) << "Solution:" << std::endl;
        LOG(INFO) << "Objective value = " << objective->Value();
        LOG(INFO) << "x = " << x->solution_value();
        LOG(INFO) << "y = " << y->solution_value();
    }

}

int main() {
    operations_research::BasicExample();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output:

```
$> myapp
WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
I0721 17:54:37.269460 1170927 main.cpp:17] Number of variables = 2
I0721 17:54:37.270126 1170927 main.cpp:24] Number of constraints = 1
W0721 17:54:37.273723 1170927 lp_solver.cc:163] 
******************************************************************
* WARNING: Glop will be very slow because it will use DCHECKs    *
* to verify the results and the precision of the solver.         *
* You can gain at least an order of magnitude speedup by         *
* compiling with optimizations enabled and by defining NDEBUG.   *
******************************************************************
I0721 17:54:37.277882 1170927 main.cpp:34] Solution:
I0721 17:54:37.277948 1170927 main.cpp:35] Objective value = 4
I0721 17:54:37.278002 1170927 main.cpp:36] x = 1
I0721 17:54:37.278023 1170927 main.cpp:37] y = 1

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: So what is your cmake configuration? `Error:` Please post the verbose compilation command. I think documentation is simple enough: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/cmake/README.md#consuming-or-tools-in-a-cmake-project and explains `How to link or-tools to my project using cmake properly?`, did you follow it? Did you remove the build directory before recompiling in any "attempted solution"?

Comment: Yes I followed each version proposed in the documentation. Most of the time either linkage error or absl missing abslConfig.cmake... Between each attempt I ran make clean_third_party.

Comment: My cmake configuration is splitted into several files, I will be working on a minimal working example and add it to the post ASAP.

Comment: Just added the the cmake configuration in the attempted solution 5.

Comment: `bsl missing abslConfig.cmake...` Great - it works. Now or-tools depends on absail, you have to install it. https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp  . https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/cmake/README.md#dependencies .

Comment: To remove the warning, please build in optimized/release mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few points (OR-Tools dev here):

- You can find 3 integration samples here: https://github.com/or-tools/cmake_or-tools

  - using local install / `find_package()`
  - using FetchContent()
  - using ExternalProject()

Basically we provide an alias library `ortools::ortools`, you should depend on it.
src: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/b37d9c786b69128f3505f15beca09e89bf078a89/cmake/cpp.cmake#L134

Otherwise, please be aware that or-tools depends on abseil-cpp and use C++17 so you must use the same langage dialect since abseil-cpp is language version dependent.

Comment: Thanks for the github, I have not check that one out. I was using c++ 20 but changing to c++ 17 did not fixed the issue.