# building OR-Tools for Blazor wasm

Tags: blazor-webassembly, webassembly, emscripten, or-tools

I am developing a Blazor wasm tool that relies on Google OR-Tools for some part and im running into problems building the library and using it in .NET 6 Blazor wasm by leveraging `NativeFileReference`.

I have been using other C++ Libraries in my application using the same approach and they build and integrate without a hiccup [see Steve Sanderson Talk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/events/dotnetconf-2021/new-blazor-webassembly-capabilities-in-net-6). but the OR-Tools has a lot of dependencies and is way more complex in structure.

my goal is to compile to a single binary which I can use and ship in my projects, where I'll write a C++ entry file that contains all the functions I need to interact with C# as in attempt no.2 below.[see also Static linking section](https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2022/dynamic-linking-in-webassembly/)

**what have I tried ? :**

1. I took a look at the [Sudoku Solver](https://medium.com/swlh/a-suduko-solving-serverless-endpoint-using-webassembly-and-or-tools-df9f7bb10044), he mentions in the article that he had to iterate over the dependencies until he got a wasm build and created patches, which I'm unsure how it was achieved. but I figured I can add the suduko example to an empty Blazor wasm project for testing, changing the `emcc` command to generate a single bindary using `- shared`  and `-s WASM=1` and removing any Javascript use. but I got a Json parse error on linking `emscripten : error : emscript: failure to parse metadata output from wasm-emscripten-finalize` which appears to be a version mismatch error according to [this](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=975069) and the [dotnet doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/webassembly-native-dependencies?view=aspnetcore-6.0#net-webassembly-build-tools), if I pass the `sudokus.cc` file I get a file not found error on headers.
2. I referred to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68467000/how-to-linking-or-tools-to-my-cmake-project) and tried to use the example as a starting point to build wasm from and simply use the `main.cpp` in the same fashion but in Blazor. that also didn't quite work.

**my questions:**

a. What is the correct way to build a wasm single binary from OR-Tools (regardless of the size) ?
b. would attempt no.2 actually work ? if so, what is additionally required to build it as is but for wasm.

Thank you!

**System Information:**
Ubuntu 21.10
gcc/g++ 11.2.0
dotnet 6.0.202
Emscripten 3.1.9

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/1670 Currently no bandwidth to work on it but PR feedback welcome !

Comment: @Mizux Thanks! I will definitely be experimenting with this a lot. awesome tool btw!

Answer (score 1):

I'll leave this here for anyone else looking to use or-tools for Blazor wasm, please note that this answer is meant for **question b.** in original question.

In the context of keeping the Blazor App light this method is useful if you want a certain job to be executed by a specific tool in or-tools. mind you that this uses a very old version of or-tools (for the time being).

1. install/downgrade Emscripten v2.0.23 (current version used in .NET wasm-tools)
2. Clone [kjartanm/wasm-or-tools](https://github.com/kjartanm/wasm-or-tools/tree/Add-Hosttools)
3. Follow build steps under *About this fork*
4. do adjustments on emcc command on entry C++ file to produce a single binary

> emcc -O3 
> --bind 
> -lm 
> -s LLD_REPORT_UNDEFINED 
> -s ERROR_ON_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=0 
> -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS='["method_in_entry_file"]' 
> -I wasmbuild/install/include 
> -Lwasmbuild/install/lib 
> -lglog 
> -labsl_bad_any_cast_impl
> -labsl_log_severity 
> -labsl_bad_optional_access
> .
> .
> .  ***list too long edit the command in example build shell script***
> /name_of_entry_file.cc 
> -shared -o output/path/output_name.o

5. Include the `.o` file in your blazor app. [see here for details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/webassembly-native-dependencies?view=aspnetcore-6.0)